# Как мне оптимизировать количество sql запросов?

Tags: python, sql, django

Постараюсь максимально понятно задать вопрос.

Есть задача: оптимизировать количество sql запросов, чтобы их стало меньше и сайт грузился быстрее, я полный новичок в backend'e, не понимаю что и как мне делать, был вариант просто добавить select & prefetch related'ов, но они уже добавлены, проект большой, я не знаю где что искать и исправлять

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(django debugger tool показывает 285 запросов)

[image: django debugger tool]

Есть ли еще какой-то способ, который я смог бы применить чтобы оптимизировать количество запросов на бд? p.s. - естественно я гуглил эту проблему перед тем как задать вопрос

Направьте меня пожалуйста, юного бэкенд-стажера, куда и как двигаться, что изучать хотя бы для решения данной задачи?

Буду рад любой помощи и поддержке, спасибо

Comment: Сами запросы можно попробовать ускорить (индексы сделать и всё такое). А в остальном это сильно зависит от структуры базы и насколько вам важно актуальные данные показывать, в том плане, что можно кэшировать, а что нет. В основном кэширование данных сильно ускоряет, но надо понимать, что можно кэшировать и на какой период времени.

Comment: @CrazyElf мне дали доступ к замороженному проекту,  нужно уменьшить количество запросов на бд и ускорить загрузку сайта.  

Если можно, скиньте пж какие-нибудь статьи или видосы по ускорению с индексами или кэшированием данных.  

Я пока сам тоже что-нибудь поищу

Comment: как минимум там указано 157 дубликатов - т.е. запросов точь в точь, тут конечно зависит от логики программы почему идет такое наложение. Убрав его скорость загрузки увеличится вдвое.

Comment: да, на дубликаты я тоже обратил внимания, но я слишком много не понимаю в коде, чтобы просто взять и пофиксить это, пока просто изучаю что можно с этим сделать

Comment: как минимум можно почитать вот это (https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/db/optimization.html, оригинал более свежий: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/optimization/ ) но я пологаю дело этим может не ограничится, хотя весьма вероятно что поможет. Возможно ваша база данных плохо спроектированна, возможно код работы с ней не оптимальный, лучше иметь доступ и к тому и другому, но все еще зависит от обстоятельств, если код заморожен, возможно можно внести корреные правки базу и переписать код. Если доступ есть только к коду то, да нужно хорошо понять как он работает прежде чем менять.

Comment: с пониманием кода как раз таки большие проблемы, проект для меня очень большой, мне необходимо оптимизировать работу с бд как можно меньше изучив код, так как на изучение всего кода у меня уйдет очень и очень много времени, ну спасибо за ссылку, почитать с документации я почему то не догадался, буду читать и что то пытаться применять

Comment: Посмотрите в подробной информации что за запрос и где вызывается. добавьте `prefetch_related` через `Prefetch` объект

Comment: Ну тут можно использовать кэширование. Посмотрите вот это видос, если надо https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3kry8telRo&t=872s